# Segfault occuring after a week of running?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I've got a C program which runs fine, but after around a week of running it always seems to segfault. I've compiled it with -g and run it through gdb and it looks like it pointing to the following code.

In my main loop I call a function (actually to try and debug why its crashing)

```
char config_debug[10];
```

I then read a conf file and based on the current setting in it, it sets config_debug to true

Then in my program I call this:

(line 312):

```
  debug("send off data",config_debug);
```

This is the function:

```
int debug(char *debug_info, char *config_debug)
{
    chomp(config_debug);
    if ( strcmp(config_debug,"true") == 0 )
            {
            FILE *fp;
            fp=fopen("/tmp/debug.log", "a");
```

(line 55):

```
            fprintf(fp, debug_info);
            fprintf(fp, "\n");
            fclose(fp);
            }
    return 0;
}  

void chomp(char *s) {
    while(*s && *s != '\n' && *s != '\r') s++;
    *s = 0;
}
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with the above 2 functions?

Here is a trace if it helps:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xb6d7a67c in vfprintf () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (gdb) bt
#0  0xb6d7a67c in vfprintf () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#1  0xb6d83cd8 in fprintf () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000a848 in debug (debug_info=0xc304 "send off data", config_debug=0xbec0cb5c "true") at station.c:55
#3  0x0000b614 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbec0cd94) at station.c:312
```

Comment: What is the value of `config_debug` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 fprintf(fp, debug_info);
```

is wrong, and incorrect (possible [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)) if `debug_info` contains a `%` (followed by some characters like `s` for instance).

You should read [fprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html), enable all warnings in the cross-compiler e.g. by compiling with `-Wall -g` passed to your cross-compiler (`clang` would have warned you and `gcc` should, at least with `-Wextra`, but perhaps does not). In your case you could simply replace that faulty `fprintf` with a simpler and faster call to [fputs(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fputs.3.html) like:

```
fputs(debug_info, fp);
```

<sup>(in emebedded applications, `fputs` is often worth using, since it is faster than `fprintf`; actually sometimes the compiler optimize `fprintf` into something simpler.)</sup>

and replace the `fprintf(fp, "\n");` with a simple `putc('\n', fp);`

<sup>BTW, it is confusing to have `config_debug` be both a global variable and a parameter. Avoid name collusions to improve readability. Be sure that `config_debug` and `debug_info` are null terminated strings.</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how I missed that.  I did compile it with -Wall and -g and it didnt throw up any errors - strange.

Answer (score 2):

```
 fprintf(fp, debug_info);
            fprintf(fp, "\n");
```

Above two statements are wrong.Modify Like this

```
 fprintf(fp,"%s", debug_info); 
            fprintf(fp,"%s", "\n");
```

see [`fprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

From @ Basile Starynkevitch comment, added.

You can also use [`fputs()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputs) and [`fputc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputc) These are simpler and more efficient.

```
 fputs(debug_info,fp); 
 fputc('\n',fp);
```

Comment: `fputs` and `putc` would have been simpler and more efficient